# next page with custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I want to be able to show the older entries for my custom post but I cant get it to work. 
The problem is that it won't display the next and previous links. I have also tried with
    `posts_nav_link();`

This is my current code.

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         =>  'category-vote',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  5,
            'paged'             =>  $paged,
        );

        $vote = new WP_query($args);
        if ( $vote->have_posts() ) :
        while($vote->have_posts()) : $vote->the_post();
    ?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php comments_number('Inga kommentarer', 'En kommentar', '% kommentarer'); ?></a>
        <?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
        <hr class ="news-hr"/> 
    <?php endwhile; ?> 

        <?php previous_posts_link('Newer') ?>
        <?php next_posts_link('Older ') ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you be more specific.

Comment: Added the problem to the question

Comment: How many category-vote post do you have?

Comment: The navigation link functions work off the main query. Why not use the native custom post type archives and an `archive-category-vote.php` template?

Comment: I have more then ten category-vote posts. I haven't tried  the archive-category-vote.php yet. How exactly do i set i up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` are using the global `$wp_query` object. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
// save the original $wp_query object
$temp = $wp_query;
// create a new $wp_query object
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();
  // output your data here
endwhile;
// display previous and next links
previous_posts_link('Newer');
next_posts_link('Older');
// restore the global $wp_query object
$wp_query = $temp;
```

Comment: @AdamLundberg - Glad I could help=)